# Can I get all the fruit types by visiting Random Islands?

Tags: animal-crossing-new-horizons, nintendo-switch-online

I don't have a Switch Online subscription, and have no intention of getting one, so the only way (aside from physical LAN meetups) that I can get fruit that isn't native to my island is to use Nook Miles Tickets and visit random islands.

This seems to have worked to get me coconuts and pears, but despite many Random Islands I haven't found any of the other 3 fruits.

Most guides and sources say that you can get random fruits from these islands, but a few individuals have said that you will only ever find one extra fruit this way. I've looked online for confirmation that this is how it works, but haven't found a solid answer.

Am I actually able to get all 6 fruit types just from Nook Miles Tickets?

Comment: It's worth noting that you can use Local connections to visit islands. This shouldn't require a NSO subscription since it doesn't use Wifi, but does require someone being physically near you.

Comment: @vanblart which is a problem given the whole "international pandemic" thing.

Comment: @MichaelCampbell But it is a solution that satisfies your predicament once stay at home orders are lifted

Comment: You're right, it does solve my personal problem (several months from now when it possible), but doesn't answer the question I wanted answered (which I was after because I couldn't find a clear answer to online). I've edited the question to be more specificly about Nook Miles Tickets.

Answer (score 13):

No, unfortunately you'll not be able to get all 6 fruit types without using online services.
Currently, the game will let you get only 4 different fruits with local play:

1. Your native fruit
2. The fruit your mom sent via e-mail
3. Coconuts on mystery islands (using [Nook-Miles Tickets](https://www.polygon.com/animal-crossing-new-horizons-switch-acnh-guide/2020/3/20/21166529/nook-miles-tickets-islands-mystery-island-tours))
4. Your sister fruit on the [Sister Fruit Mystery Island](https://www.nintendocastle.com/animal-crossing-new-horizons/fruit-trees/)

PS: It's not possible to know which is your sister fruit until you visit the island for the first time. But then, when you visit this same island again, it will always be the same sister fruit you found the first time.

PS²: There are rumours you can receive different fruit from villagers as a mail gift, but I personally never experienced this.

Comment: I believe the sister fruit and fruit from your mom is the same. My main island is Peaches and Mom/Sister are Oranges. My wife is seeing the same thing in her game - unless we're both just unlucky and they happen to match in both cases.

Comment: Also - might be worth adding a source with details on Nook miles tickets: https://www.polygon.com/animal-crossing-new-horizons-switch-acnh-guide/2020/3/20/21166529/nook-miles-tickets-islands-mystery-island-tours

Comment: @vanblart I think they can be different... the original fruit on my island was apples, mom sent me oranges, and the only other fruit besides apples I've seen in my numerous nook mile tours is cherries.

Comment: Same, native is orange, mom fruit was apple (I sold it, silly that I am), and my sister fruit is pear.

Comment: Is it sure it's not possible? Maybe the probability is very low..? the article in your link says it's a 9% for sister fruit. The others are maybe below 1%

Comment: @vanblart I think you were unlucky ;( My native fruits were oranges, my mom sent apples, and my sister fruit was peach. PS: I added the link you suggested, thanks!

Comment: -1 you need to back this up with reliable sources that explain where the information is coming from

Answer (score -3):

Yes, although it's rare. The game is designed and balanced to be able to fully experience everything (except the obvious multiplayer), without a subscription. nook islands will have different fruit on them as special islands. Most often you will only get your native fruit, but I was able to get all except 1 fruit through nook islands only. Be prepared to spend a lot of miles jumping to various islands though.

Comment: This answer is patently incorrect. You cannot get "all but one" fruit from the mystery islands. You get all but **two** fruits (or, if some accounts are to be believed where the mom fruit and sister fruit were the same, all but three)

Comment: This is kind of the problem though isn't it? Lots of folks citing like, Polygon saying it's not possible, and then a few individuals saying that they have personally done it.

Comment: you can get them all offline. as i have a friend who did so. i got my last fruit online since i had a subscription, but wanted to see if it was possible without one. and it very much is. it's just that with rae and special rare islands, the chance is very low (i spent quite a few miles, easily close to 200k)

Comment: The sister fruit thing was confirmed via data mining.

Comment: @Flater what is your source? Because you’re making a negative generalization a single positive instance proves you wrong. I have just as much reason to believe you as people claiming from personal experience that it’s possible.

Comment: @Era: This question is incredibly common on the subreddit, which I've followed since release. It's pretty much the first question new players ask, as fruits are the first thing you really focus on collecting. Not once has anyone claimed that this is the case. Also, the "one instance disproves the rule" is useful in empirical research but less relevant for games, as games follow simple logical rules, and you're not likely to encounter an _intentional_ exception to the rules (i.e. ignoring bugs and glitches).

Comment: @Flater you’re misinterpreting my point, which is about the logical structure of the claim. Think universal claim vs. existential claim. The question is what the rules of the game are. I’m not stating you’re wrong, I’m saying you need to back up what you’re claiming with more concrete evidence.

Comment: @Era: Along the same line of "one disproves the rule", you also cannot prove a negative. The onus is on you to put forth the exception, not on me to disprove.

Comment: @Flater you can absolutely prove your claim. For example, I’ve heard of people decompiling the game code to identify the algorithms for certain mechanics. This could easily prove how acquiring fruit is possible. An official statement from Nintendo would also be reliable. These are just examples.

Comment: @Era: Find me **one** reliable source that provably contradicts my statement. It's not like this question hasn't been asked online, so finding one should be easy, right?

Comment: I've seen plenty of folks on the Reddit claiming this is possible, and several claiming to have gotten all the fruit from mystery islands. So plenty of folks have "claimed this is the case".
None of them have provided any good evidence beyond "Well, it worked for me" though.

Comment: @Flater I’m not asserting the opposite of your claim, I’m asking for evidence for your claim. I don’t need to provide evidence to ask for evidence.